# How hard is it to DIY soldering (reflow smt) a image sensor\silicon die to FFC cable?

Tags: soldering, image-sensor, ffc

I have a need of a rapid prototype of a image sensor and rolling my own image sensor die.

For example, what if I wanted to mount an AR0130cs sensor to an FFC? I don't care about dust or contamination, I also don't care about alignment. I need a prototype.

[image]
https://www.onsemi.com/download/data-sheet/pdf/ar0130cs-d.pdf

Looking at the pitch, its 0.7mm (~30mil) which is large and not anything too crazy.

***Has anyone done this?*** Can I mount an image sensor like this to an FFC with standard reflow processes? Is it like soldering a QFN?

I'm also not worried about the FFC design, I'm fairly confident that I could have that manufactured and do the proper layout for said cable.

Comment: PLCC or ILCC? It matters a lot. For PLCC there are sockets which might make life a lot easier in this case.

Comment: The picture shows PLCC... what is the difference? I don't think I can increase the height but I'll ask.

Comment: No, the picture shows an ILCC. PLCC is the older package with "spring" legs used for socket mounting - they can be soldered too but that's far from ideal. ILCC is plain SMD for reflow soldering. PLCC will be much taller and I don't recommend that package at all, other than for lab purposes.

Comment: I had some crazy idea of soldering FFC connectors directly onto the ILCC package, to create a rather brittle lab thing. Though with PLCC you could perhaps create a more professional lab PLC with socket mount and attach FFC to that one. Depending on your prototype budget and time to deliver, naturally.

Answer (score 2):

According to page 46 of the [Onsemi soldering manual](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/collateral/solderrm-d.pdf), their image sensors can be reflow soldered using both leaded and lead-free processes. The circuit board substrate material shouldn't matter, but of course, the FFC needs to be secured to a flat surface during soldering.

If your sensor is particularly sensitive to heat, you could also consider using SnBi (tin-bismuth) solder paste, which melts at around 140°C. Another thing to consider is a rigid-flex PCB to make the mounting area for the sensor more rigid and even.

A quick Google Images search ("CCTV PCB") also turned up a lot of PCBs with an image sensor soldered directly onto them in what appears to be a standard reflow process. For example:

[image: CCTV camera PCB with sensor soldered on]

[Image source](https://de.aliexpress.com/item/1005002526041570.html)

Comment: What about the other questions? Have you tried it?

Comment: @VoltageSpike I haven't personally done it, but I've found some examples of PCBs with soldered-on image sensors online. I've updated the answer with one of them.

Comment: Thats on a PCB and yeah it can be done, but just because they exist doesn't mean I know anything about the process, what about an FFC?